# Parsing decoded JSON in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I would like some help on how to access specific fields once I decode JSON with Aeson.

I would like some tips on the best way to to access a field or list of fields once I am at this point.

For example from below. The data contains descriptions of 2 products. How would I return the 2 `sku` fields ie `["ABCDEF","CDEFG"]` or even how to access the entire `Identity` data type for both products.

My output is:

**DECODED JSON**

```
Just (Response {response = [Body {productId = 5555, brandId = 10, productTypeId = 1, identity = Identity {sku = "ABCDEF", ean = "1111", barcodls {taxable = False, taxCode = TaxCode {taxCodeId = 7, code = "T1"}}, variations = [Variation {optionId = 1, optionName = "option1", optionVal111221", barcode = "2443222"}, productGroupId = 17, stock = Stock {stockTracked = True, weight = Weight {magnitude = 0.0}, dimensions = Dimensption1", optionValueId = 5, optionValue = "5"},Variation {optionId = 2, optionName = "option2", optionValueId = 14, optionValue = "14"}]}]})
```

Here is the original JSON

**JSON**

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 5555,
      "brandId": 10,
      "productTypeId": 1,
      "identity": {
        "sku": "ABCDEF",
        "ean": "1111",
        "barcode": "2222"
      },
      "productGroupId": 17,
      "stock": {
        "stockTracked": true,
        "weight": {
          "magnitude": 0
        },
        "dimensions": {
          "length": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "volume": 0
        }
      },
      "financialDetails": {
        "taxable": false,
        "taxCode": {
          "id": 7,
          "code": "T1"
        }
      },
      "variations": [
        {
          "optionId": 1,
          "optionName": "option1",
          "optionValueId": 5,
          "optionValue": "5"
        },
        {
          "optionId": 2,
          "optionName": "option2",
          "optionValueId": 14,
          "optionValue": "OS"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 9999,
      "brandId": 10,
      "productTypeId": 1,
      "identity": {
        "sku": "CDEFG",
        "ean": "111221",
        "barcode": "2443222"
      },
      "productGroupId": 17,
      "stock": {
        "stockTracked": true,
        "weight": {
          "magnitude": 0
        },
        "dimensions": {
          "length": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "volume": 0
        }
      },
      "financialDetails": {
        "taxable": false,
        "taxCode": {
          "id": 7,
          "code": "T1"
        }
      },
      "variations": [
        {
          "optionId": 1,
          "optionName": "option1",
          "optionValueId": 5,
          "optionValue": "5"
        },
        {
          "optionId": 2,
          "optionName": "option2",
          "optionValueId": 14,
          "optionValue": "14"
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

and here is my code so far:

**CODE**

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson 
import Control.Applicative 
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS


jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "test.json"

getJSON :: IO BS.ByteString
getJSON = BS.readFile jsonFile

main :: IO ()
main = do
     input <- getJSON
     let json = decode input :: Maybe Response
     case json of
        Nothing -> print "error parsing JSON"
        Just m  -> print json


data Response = Response
    { response :: [Body]
    } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Response where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Response <$> v .: "response"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data Body = Body
    { productId         :: Int
    , brandId           :: Int
    , productTypeId     :: Int
    , identity          :: Identity
    , productGroupId    :: Int
    , stock             :: Stock
    , financialDetails  :: FinancialDetails
    , variations        :: [Variation]
    } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Body where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Body
        <$> v .: "id"
        <*> v .: "brandId"
        <*> v .: "productTypeId"
        <*> v .: "identity"
        <*> v .: "productGroupId"
        <*> v .: "stock"
        <*> v .: "financialDetails"
        <*> v .: "variations"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data Identity = Identity
    { sku       :: String
    , ean       :: String
    , barcode   :: String
    } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Identity where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Identity
        <$> v .: "sku"
        <*> v .: "ean"
        <*> v .: "barcode"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data Stock = Stock
    { stockTracked  :: Bool
    , weight        :: Weight
    , dimensions    :: Dimensions
    } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Stock where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Stock
        <$> v .: "stockTracked"
        <*> v .: "weight"
        <*> v .: "dimensions"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data Weight = Weight 
    { magnitude             :: Double
    } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Weight where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Weight
        <$> v .: "magnitude"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data Dimensions = Dimensions                
    { length                :: Double
    , height                :: Double
    , width                 :: Double
    , volume                :: Double  
    } deriving (Show) 

instance FromJSON Dimensions where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Dimensions
        <$> v .: "length"
        <*> v .: "height"
        <*> v .: "width"
        <*> v .: "volume"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data FinancialDetails = FinancialDetails    
    { taxable               :: Bool
    , taxCode               :: TaxCode
    } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON FinancialDetails where
    parseJSON (Object v) = FinancialDetails
        <$> v .: "taxable"
        <*> v .: "taxCode"
    parseJSON _ = mempty

data TaxCode = TaxCode                     
    { taxCodeId                   :: Int
    , code                  :: String
    } deriving (Show)  

instance FromJSON TaxCode where
    parseJSON (Object v) = TaxCode
        <$> v .: "id"
        <*> v .: "code"
    parseJSON _ = mempty     

data Variation = Variation         
    { optionId              :: Int
    , optionName            :: String
    , optionValueId         :: Int
    , optionValue           :: String
    }  deriving (Show) 

instance FromJSON Variation where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Variation
        <$> v .: "optionId"
        <*> v .: "optionName"
        <*> v .: "optionValueId"
        <*> v .: "optionValue"
    parseJSON _ = mempty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem I would turn to the `lens` library.  While this is a rather large dependency, it can be very useful for drilling down into your data.  Be warned, `lens` is a beast powered by a lot of mathematics that is usually beyond the layperson, but in a lot of cases it's one of those libraries that "just works".  In order to make it work easily (i.e. without having to write all the lenses yourself) you need the `TemplateHaskell` extension and you'll need to change all of your types so that their fields start with an underscore, so

```
data Response = Response
    { _response :: [Body]
    } deriving (Show)
```

and so on for your other types.  Your JSON parsing will be fine, though.

Then you need to just import `Control.Lens`.  One caveat is that it exports a type called `Identity` that will clash with yours so

```
import Control.Lens hiding (Identity)
```

Then at the bottom of the file just place the following lines

```
makeLenses ''Response
makeLenses ''Body
makeLenses ''Identity
makeLenses ''Stock
makeLenses ''Weight
makeLenses ''Dimensions
makeLenses ''FinancialDetails
makeLenses ''TaxCode
makeLenses ''Variation
```

This uses template haskell to generate a bunch of functions for you called lenses.  These have a weird type that I won't go into now (there's [plenty of tutorials](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lens) out there), but all of them will be the same as your field names minus the underscore.

These new functions let you do some pretty crazy things.  For example, if you wanted all of the `sku`s inside a response you can just do

```
> -- Unwrap the Maybe here
> Just json <- decode <$> getJSON
> toListOf (response.traversed.identity.sku) json
["ABCDEF", "CDEFG"]
> -- Or as an alternative to toListOf you can use the operator ^..
> json^..response.traversed.identity.sku
["ABCDEF", "CDEFG"]
```

If you just want to access a field you can use the `^.` operator, or if you want to index into a list you'll probably also want the `^?` operator which allows for safe indexing (returns `Nothing` if you go out of bounds)

```
> json^?response.ix 0.identity
Just (Identity {_sku="ABCDEF", _ean="111", _barcode="222"})
> let Just ident = json^?response.ix 0.identity
> ident^.sku
"ABCDEF"
```

Of course, you can do all this without resorting to `lens`.  It could look something like

```
allSkus :: Response -> [String]
allSkus r = map (_sku . _identity) $ _response r
```

Which isn't too bad, but what if you wanted to change the value in the first identity?  With `lens` you can perform sets as well (obviously still working with immutable values):

```
> let newjson = (response.ix 0.identity.sku .~ "FOOBAR") json
> newjson^..response.traversed.identity.sku
["FOOBAR", "CDEFG"]
```

This is to illustrate how powerful `lens` can be.  It's a complicated framework, more of its own language inside Haskell and it takes a while to learn, but it can be very good at expressing what you want to do rather than how to do it.

Comment: this is brilliant and your explanations are very clear. Thanks again.